# what are the weakest preconditions of these following statements

Tags: automata, programming-languages

what is the meaning of postcondition and weakest postcondition in terms of programing and what are weakest postconditons of following statements.

```
1. a=2*(b-1)-1   {a>0}
2. b=(c+10)/3    {b>6}
3. a=(a+2*b-1)   {a>1}
4. a=2*b+1;b=a-3 {b<0}
```

Comment: I suggest repeating the material. They should explain what *precondition* and *weakest precondition* mean, hopefully with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the first one. You want to find what condition on $b$ will imply $2(b-1)-1>0$. All you have to do is solve this inequality.

The other ones are similar.